# How can I move an arduino library into my project repo and use it from there?

Tags: arduino-uno

I've got this project that that is using the LiquidCrystal.h library. My import looks like this...

```
#import <LiquidCrystal.h>
```

I've tried making a 'libraries' folder in my repo, and copying the LiquidCrystal directory from arduino's global libraries folder to my_project/libraries and changing my import to...

```
#import "libraries/LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal.h"
```

and it explodes on me. I know the path is right, because it gives me a different error if I change the import path to be wrong... but even when it's right, I get this traceback...

```
Arduino: 1.8.1 (Mac OS X), TD: 1.36, Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

/var/folders/sz/cdsmvqws6rq9839mhd802prm0000gp/T//cc4gIISN.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/Users/chris/art/greenhouse/greenhouse/greenhouse.ino:36: undefined reference to `LiquidCrystal::LiquidCrystal(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
etc....
```

What's the deal? Aren't I supposed to be able to import libraries with an absolute path to the library? This is literally the same file.

What is the difference between `#import <foo.h>` and `#import "my_libraries/myfoo.h"` ?

Answer (score 2):

> What's the deal? Aren't I supposed to be able to import libraries with
>   an absolute path to the library? This is literally the same file.

Yes you can use both absolute and relative paths, but "libraries/LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal.h" is a relative path because it doesn't start from `C:\\` or `/` basically. Also make sure you get the `LiquidCrystal.cpp` file which actually contains all the functions `LiquidCrystal.h` specifies.

> What is the difference between #import  and #import
>   "my_libraries/myfoo.h" ?

`#include "my_libraries/myfoo.h"` specifies that `myfoo.h` is in a folder `my_libraries` first searched for in `current_folder/my_libraries/myfoo.h` then quote directories and rest of the search paths later, `#include <foo.h>` specifies that `foo.h` is a system header, it's only searched for in search paths.

Solution here would be saying inside your sketch that it is in a subfolder, that the folder is one folder below and then two folders deeper for ex. `#include "../libraries/LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal.h"` this here assumes your sketch is in `root_folder/Sketch/Sketch.ino` and library in `root_folder/libraries/LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this folder structure:

```
my_project
|_src
  |_LiquidCrystal
```

and change the import to:

```
#import "src/LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal.h"
```

Since Arduino IDE 1.6.10, recursive compilation of the sketch folder has been limited to the `src` subfolder (see [Arduino/arduino-builder#148](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder/pull/148)).

By the way, it's much more common to use `#include` instead of `#import`, which is deprecated and will cause a compiler warning. Any properly written library will not require the use of `#import`.